# Apache Activemq and Mqtt

Tags: apache, jms, activemq-classic, mqtt

I am trying to use Apache ActiveMQ as my MQTT broker. Everything is straightforward and i can send messages from JMS broker to MQTT client and vice versa.

I've got a question which i couldn't found anywhere. Is there a method or mechanism available which lets MQTT client to define "message selector" like JMS clients and consumers.

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

The only way for MQTT Clients do decide what Messages to get is by subscriptions.

These can either be a concrete Topic ("Aaaa/Bbbb/Cccc") or a Wildcard Topic string ("aa/#/cc" or "aa/bb/+/cc")

Comment: The `#` wildcard can only be the last element in the topic. e.g. `aa/bb/#` is valid, `aa/#/bb` is not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create ACL file in which you can define certain Topics on which client can subscribe... 
And you can do one more thing.. you can also  define topic on user authentication bases .. it means different users are permitted on different topics accordingly.